# UISearchBar Show keyboard

Tags: swift

I have an action to call `searchBar`. When it is called, i want the keyboard to show up.

How can i show the keyboard?

This is the code with my action:

```
@IBAction func Searappear(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchBar.hidden=false
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Jens A. Koch, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`.

Comment: Awesome, if the answer solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.